# OOP sort Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a superclass Fruits and subclasses Banana, Mango, Apple, Orange.

I've already added them into `ArrayList<Fruits> fruit = new ArrayList<Fruits>();`.

I need to sort this array by order of subclass Banana, Orange, Mango, Apple.

I 've tried to do it by `Collections.sort` and using a comparator.

Comment: So what's your question...

Comment: What is the "order of subclass"?

Comment: i think the question is how to sort with a custom predicate

Comment: Banana, Mango ,Apple, Orange are all subclasses and they all add in the same Arraylist . I need to sort this arraylist like this: the elements which is Object Banana display first and then to the others

Comment: subclasses Banana will be the first elements in Arraylist and then to the others.That's how I need to sort it (Sorry , I'm not a native English speaker so u may find hard to understand.)

Comment: If you can't use a comparator -  either make your interface implement Comparable (using a default method) if you're using Java 8, or in each one of the subclasses if you're using a lower version of Java.

Answer (score 0):

If sorting by class is really what you need to do, simply create a comparator that sees which Fruit's class appears first on a list:

```
    Collections.sort(fruit, new Comparator<Fruits>() {
        /* Sorts by asking what class the fruit has. Depending on the
         * logic behind this sort order, it may be more appropriate to sort
         * based on a static method call asking about the real reason the
         * fruits are to be sorted in this order. The problem with this method
         * is that you cannot add additional subclasses of Fruit without also
         * putting them into the sort order.
         */
        final Class[] sortOrder = new Class[]{Banana.class, Orange.class, Mango.class, Apple.class};
        @Override
        public int compare(Fruits o1, Fruits o2) {
            for (int i = 0; i < sortOrder.length; i++) {
                if (o1.getClass() == sortOrder[i]) {
                    if (o2.getClass() == sortOrder[i])
                        return 0; //same class
                    else
                        return -1; //o1's class was first on list
                } else if (o2.getClass() == sortOrder[i])
                    return 1; //o2's class was first on list
            }
            //if we're here, then neither class was found on the list.
            return 0; //may also be appropriate to throw an exception.
        }
    });
```

However, it doesn't make much sense to sort by class. As discussed in the comment at the top at the code, it is likely more appropriate to ask each object about the property that makes the fruits be sorted in that particular order, and use that to sort.

Comment: Thanks a lot .Actually I have that part too but I did it. Only this  I have difficulty dealing with

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can use a default method to implement Comparable:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fruit banana = new Banana();
        Fruit orange = new Orange();
        Fruit mango = new Mango();
        List<Fruit> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        arr.add(mango);
        arr.add(orange);
        arr.add(banana);
        System.out.println(arr);
        Collections.sort(arr);
        System.out.println(arr);
    }
}

interface Fruit extends Comparable<Fruit> {

    @Override
    default public int compareTo(Fruit other) {
        return this.getClass().getName().compareTo(other.getClass().getName());
    }
}

class Banana implements Fruit {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getName();
    }
}
class Orange implements Fruit {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getName();
    }
}

class Mango implements Fruit {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getName();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[Mango, Orange, Banana] // before sorting
[Banana, Mango, Orange] // after sorting
```

Comment: Thanks but it seems to sort in alphabetical order.

Comment: @user4387235 of course it does - that's how I implemented it (as an example). If you want a different implementation you'll have to modify the method `compareTo()` and adjust it to your needs.